# Execute SpecFlow specs (.feature files) without compilation

Tags: specflow

I want to be able to execute given SpecFlow (Gherkin) .feature file locally without doing compilation.

So workflow would be (as a Business Analyst or a QA engineer):
1. modify .feature file (using predefined vocabulary of steps)
2. run

```
SpecFlowSuperTool.exe
    /feature:.\FoobarprojectSpecs.feature
    /assembly:Foobarproject.dll,Foobarproject.Core.dll
```

3. get a report

Goal is to be able to execute feature on-demand without having to recompile the code if only features have changed.

It feels like it should be a pretty straight-forward task to implement such a tool since Gherkin steps binding happens at run-time (judging by the NUnit code generated by SpecFlow).

I do understand that generate->compile->run scenario is supported already, but compile step seems unnecessary in some cases.

**UPDATE**
I ended up coding the tool myself. SpecFlow API is very simple, it was pretty easy to build a specflowrunner.exe that would take a directory or a file + configuration file, and execute .feature files directly, without creating a unit tests first.

Comment: I don't see how this can be possible. A new scenario requires a new NUnit test to be generated, so compilation is required. A change to an existing scenario requires the existing test to run statements in a different order so a change to the code and so compilation. How exactly do you imagine this working?

Comment: Generating unit tests is not necessary. It was pretty straightforward do build a console app that consumes .feature files and executes them directly, rather than taking a unit-test-generation detour.

Comment: @THX-1138, Can you share the code? I would like SpecFlow to pick up the .feature files from a directory, directly without generating a feature.cs file. I have a similar question on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480480/execute-test-using-updated-feature-file-without-compilation)

Comment: @THX-1138 I very much would like to use your tool. I have thought of the same and searching for possible implementation. Is this on Github?

Comment: I was able to do this by xUnitAdapter and its documented here http://www.rdagumampan.com/post/2018/06/how-to-execute-specflow-features-without-recompilation-or-visual-studio/

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about SpecFlow.exe ;)

Actually there's a few steps involved and [I blogged about it using MsTest about a year ago](http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/specflowexe-and-mstest.html).

The basic steps are:

1. Use SpecFlow.exe (with switch generateall) to generate tests from the .feature files.
2. Run tests and create a report. In my example i'm using MsTest but NUnit will work just fine.
3. Use SpecFlow.exe again (with switch mstestexecutionreport in my case) to generate the report.

You are more than welcome to use [my batfiles if you want](https://github.com/marcushammarberg/Demo-Reporting-with-MsTest)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you Marcus, this step requires compilation step. Which is what I would like to avoid. I am looking for a more FIT-like workflow solution.

Comment: OK - but if you just skip the first step in my description you can do this without compilation. But then you have to be able to access compiled dll's somewhere of course.

Comment: @THX-1138 - Spec flow generates .net code when you edit the feature file.  So changing the feature file changes the code.

Comment: @Chat: SpecFlow.exe does generate a code. Which is why I am asking if there is a way to execute specs skipping the code generation step. Generated code only handles binding of various pre/post events. The binding of individual steps still happens at run time.

Comment: @THX-1138 - It is possible to change the feature in ways that it would need to compile first.  The editor does not have the logic to tell if the change would require a compile before running.  I believe you can change it so that it only builds the test project when you want to run the spec-flow tests. But it will still force the compile of the test project.