# Execute Test using updated .feature file without compilation

Tags: mstest, specflow

I want to be able to change my feature file from outside visual studio and have the updated feature file picked up, for subsequent test execution, without compilation of my test project. Is it possible to do this? Can someone help to specify the exact steps needed to do this? I am using MsTest.

Here are the steps I followed, but I get the message "No tests to execute." every time:

1. Change Test Project file (.csproj) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild)
2. Build the Test DLL from Visual Studio
3. Kept the feature file in a folder FeatureFiles, under the Test release folder
4. Changed the feature file in Notepad
5. Used the Specflow generate all command, to regenerate the tests:

   > Specflow generateall TestProject.csproj /force /verbose
6. Create the report:

   > mstest /testcontainer:Test.Dll  /resultsfile:TestResult.trx

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506378/execute-specflow-specs-feature-files-without-compilation) was asked earlier, and I am following the same steps as mentioned by Marcus there.

**Update**
Here is what I would like to do. Considering the following .feature file:

Feature: Score Calculation

As a player
  I want the system to calculate my total score
  So that I know my performance

Scenario: Another beginners game
  Given a new bowling game
  When I roll the following series: 2,7,3,4,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1
  Then my total score should be 40

*In the above feature file, I would like to change the data series of numbers and change the total score and run the same test again to check if it runs fine and I get a correct score*

Comment: If you look at the linked question it has since been updated with some extra info which may be useful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to change the data for a test, then go with a CSV file that you save inside your VS project. Then in a `Given` statement open that file, parse it and save it to the `ScenarioContext.Current` object for use in subsequent steps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how what you want is possible. SpecFlow generates unit test classes from the feature file. These unit test classes **MUST** be compiled before they can be run, the same as **ANY** code change.

You are getting a 'no tests to execute' because you are still running against the old version of the dll, which doesn't contain any tests because you have not rebuilt it with the new code that specflow has generated.

From what is stated in the linked question it seems they are saying that some changes may be able to be run without recompiling, but honestly I cannot see how that is possible, and even if some feature file changes were possible I imagine that the solution would be specific to certain unit test frameworks and unsupported.

**EDIT**

When I look at the generated feature.cs file you have this:

```
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute()]
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.DescriptionAttribute("Another beginners game")]
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestPropertyAttribute("FeatureTitle", "Score Calculation")]
    public virtual void AnotherBeginnersGame()
    {
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo scenarioInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo("Another beginners game", ((string[])(null)));
        #line 5
        this.ScenarioSetup(scenarioInfo);
        #line 6
        testRunner.Given("a new bowling game", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Given ");
        #line 7
        testRunner.When("I roll the following series: 2,7,3,4,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,1", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "When ");
        #line 8
        testRunner.Then("my total score should be 40", ((string)(null)), ((TechTalk.SpecFlow.Table)(null)), "Then ");
        #line hidden
        this.ScenarioCleanup();
    }
```

As you can see this contains your actual list of values and expected result *in the code*

This surely implies that you can't change the feature file and have the test update without recompiling, as otherwise any changes to the cs file will not be reflected in the actual dll that you are running.

Comment: I would just like to change the Test data which is included in the .feature file. I had done this with Cucumber/Selenium/Java earlier for a web application, where I could just change the data in the .feature file and have it run with different sets of data. I wanted to do the same with a standalone application. So, every time I need to work with just a new set of Test Data, a recompile seems to be an overhead

Comment: can you specify exactly what you mean by 'test data' perhaps with an example (update the question)? Do you mean Scenario examples or changes to the data held in the arguments in the step?

Comment: If you look at the generated files, the data is hard coded in the feature.cs file, so even just changing the scenario examples would need a recompile

Comment: @stamhaney posted a reply. not sure you'll like it though :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see. It is surprising that just to change some data, a recompile is needed. I will wait for some time, to check if someone else has a different answer, otherwise will accept yours. Thanks again.

Comment: no problem. take your time, hopefully someone has a better solution.